# Can't pass select values to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, controller

I'm having a difficult time passing my Select values on my View to the controller. 
I have two items on my view which I wish to return to the model, where I can call in the controller. Heres what I have so far.

```
<label for="phone" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Phone Number:</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PhoneNumber, new { @class = "field-margin", id="phone",   type="tel", placeholder="Phone Number"})

<p></p>
<div><p>Save phone for future purchases?</p>
<select name="SavePhone"id ="SavePhone" class="SavePhone" data-role="select">   
<option value="false" @(Model.SavePhone == false ? "selected" : "")>No</option>             
<option value="true"  @(Model.SavePhone == true ? "selected" : "")>Yes</option>                 
</select><
```

I'm not exactly sure how to call the second part for the select options. However the top part of my code which accepts the phone number works. My naming in the model, controller, and view all are the same so I'm not sure what to do next. If you have any suggestions it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Edit

I figured out a part of my problem, Since I am loading this as

```
@Html.Partial("MobilePhoneView", Model)
```

after I click continue on the first page, it loads the view with my two options and hits the select block before it even displays. Is there some kind of work around for this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: i want to return either the value of true or false in Model.SavePhone after submission of my form to the controller. I am already passing in the model and I know the post works since the top part of my code above works fine.

Comment: And what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @Andrei It does not pass the value correctly, I'm not even sure if the syntax is right for the second part. Is that how you normally pass values when in a select drop down list?

Comment: Syntax seems ok, see my answer for the only possible problem I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using AJAX. If you have following HTML

```
<select name="SavePhone"id ="SavePhone" class="SavePhone" data-role="select">
<option value="false">No</option>             
<option value="true">Yes</option>                 
</select>
```

Then , you can simply use following to sent your choice to controller:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $("form").submit(function () { 
        $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("MethodName","ControllerName")',
           type: 'POST',
           cache: false,
           data: { Selected: $("#SavePhone").val() },
           success: function (data) {
             //
           }
         });
  });
  )};
</script>
```

You will get this value in the controller

```
private string MethodName (string Selected)
{
  String value = Selected;
  return "OK"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problem with your code might be with `selected` attribute. Not all browsers understand just `selected` (I believe this is HTML5 way of setting such attributes), though all should understand `selected="selected"`. So what you can try is:

```
<select name="SavePhone"id ="SavePhone" class="SavePhone" data-role="select">   
    <option value="false" @(Model.SavePhone == false ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>No</option>             
    <option value="true"  @(Model.SavePhone == true ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "")>Yes</option>                 
</select>
```

Comment: I figured out a part of my problem, Since I am loading this as
@Html.Partial("MobilePhoneView", Model) , after I click continue, it loads the view with my two options and hits the select block before it even displays. Is there some kind of work around for this? I'm really unsure of what to do now..

Comment: I found the root of my problem, I require to create a @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SavePhone, [list of true or false], ...) 
something like this should work. Do you know how to implement this>